# Clickhouse UPDATE Decimal(P,S) precision

Tags: decimal, rounding, clickhouse, alter

diving into ClickHouse for my new DB setup.

Read UPDATE in ClickHouse, trying to keep it super minimal (<0.1% on 2 billion rows).

Here's the kicker: I'm trying to update a Decimal(19,5) field from 19.39999 to 19.4, but it's pulling a disappearing act. Any idea how to tweak settings to make it behave?

Or should I just go old school and delete-insert if the difference is < X? What's this mysterious X that's playing hard to get? Any intel from the documentation sleuths out there?

An Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID Int64, Name String, Value Float64, val Decimal(19,5), Date Date ) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY ID;

INSERT INTO TestTable (ID, Name, Value, val, Date) VALUES (1, 'John Doe', 42.5, 19.39999, '2023-01-01');

ALTER TABLE TestTable UPDATE val = 19.4 WHERE ID = 1

SELECT * FROM TestTable
Query id: 0568d5fb-b182-4a3d-967d-910f2ecce942
┌─ID─┬─Name─────┬─Value─┬──────val─┬───────Date─┐
│  1 │ John Doe │  42.5 │ 19.39999 │ 2023-01-01 │
└────┴──────────┴───────┴──────────┴────────────┘
1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untortunatelly 19.4 is float64 type value by defaultm which have internal representation related to IEE 754 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 AS 19.399999999(9) (in period), which will lose precision during conversion to Decimal, and show as 19.4 because it's a string during output

Look details https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/859a26b7-4182-4d07-bd88-79448ea213ab
as a trick try to use

```sql
ALTER TABLE TestTable UPDATE val = toDecimal32(toString(19.4),5) WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! Worked!
(I ended up using toDecimal128 because I read Decimal(19,5) are Decimal128 but really don't understanding so deep to understand if it can brings some other error or not. Would appreciate an extra help on this: toDecimal128 instead of toDecimal32 - which one is the best)